# Chart labels broken when calculating worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

When calculating my worksheet using VBA's

```
Worksheet.Calculate
```

method, the labels of all charts on the Worksheet are displayed wrong. When using the *sheet calculate* button from the excel menu, the problem is solved. How can I get my code to do the same as *Sheet calculate* in excel?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try recording a macro when you do it manually to see the code that can be used.

Comment: Recording gives me the Worksheet.Calculate method which results in the wrong label.